# Tell Capybara to wait until iframe has loaded (is ready)

Tags: iframe, cucumber, capybara

Is there an elegant way to do this? At the moment i just use a custom step
"And wait 10 seconds" to be absolutely sure, there is enough time for the iframe to get ready. I don't want this feature to fail on my underpowered CI VM because of a small network issue or cpu spikes. But this means that the feature suite wastes a lot of time, and as you know, if the test suite takes a long time, one often doesn't bother to run it outside the CI server.

Comment: selenium-webdriver with chrome

Answer (score 18, accepted):

If you know what's going to be in your iframe you could do:

```
within_frame 'iframe_selector' do
    wait_until(10) do
        page.should have_content("Content you're waiting for")
    end
end
```

The `wait_until` method will keep waiting for 10 seconds or until the condition `page.should` returns true.

Comment: thnx, that should be sufficient

Comment: Note that with the latest capybara have_content automatically waits, so you would no need the wait_until